# A smaller sphere purely rolling down without slipping over another larger sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotation, rotational-kinematics

[image]
**In this question we have to find out the angular velocity of the smaller sphere about its own axis at the instant it leaves the surface of the larger sphere and it is given that the smaller sphere is purely rolling over the larger sphere throughout its motion.**

I tried it using two methods.

**Method 1**- 
The angle at which the sphere leaves the larger sphere can be found out using

$$mgcos(\theta) = mv^2/(R+r)$$

Next applying energy conservation about the smaller sphere's own axis

$$\frac{1}{2}(mv^2) + \frac{1}{2}(\frac{2}{5}mr^2)(\frac{v}{r})^2 = mg(R+r)(1-cos(\theta))$$

The first term in this equation denotes the translational kinetic energy and the second term the rotational kinetic energy.

from here we get value of v and then $angular velocity= \frac{v}{r}$.

**Method 2**-
using the 1st condition as in method 1 we get, angle at which the sphere leaves the larger sphere

Next I tried to apply the energy conservation equation about the axis of the larger sphere, and am ending up with a wrong answer. 
On the left hand side the first term is the rotational kinetic energy of the smaller sphere about the centre of the larger sphere. The second term denotes the rotational kinetic energy of the smaller sphere(due to rotation about its own axis)

$$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{2}{5}mr^2 + m(R+r)^2)(\frac{v}{R+r})^2 + \frac{1}{2}(\frac{2}{5}mr^2)(\frac{v}{r})^2 = mg(R+r)(1-cos(\theta))$$

Please note that it is a genuine doubt encountered while trying to do the question through other methods.

Comment: Can you elucidate why you believe $mgcos(\theta) = mv^2/(R+r)$?

Comment: @Gert As the smaller sphere is about to leave the surface of the larger sphere, the normal reaction contact force will be considered zero. mgcos(θ) - N = mv^2/(R+r), where N denotes the normal reaction by the larger sphere.

Comment: How did you define $\theta$?

Comment: @Gert Sorry I forgot to mention that. θ is the angle made by the radius vector at the point where the smaller sphere leaves the larger sphere with the vertical. I have edited the figure. Thanks!

Comment: @Gert According to you angle θ=90 degrees. But this cannot be as the sphere will escape the surface before 90 degrees. Using the equation I had written in the previous post(i.e. equation of sphere's circular motion written by drawing its free body diagram). N=0 because it leaves the surface.

Comment: You are correct. But I think I see where you're going wrong too. Will post it if I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Which is right?

So let's first establish what is correct. Suppose we have a circle of radius $r$ and mass $m$ centered on a circle of radius $\bar R$ (not quite what you have defined; in your case $\bar R = R + r$). We'll say that the position of the $r$-circle on the $\bar R$-circle is angle $\phi$ and, from the angle $\phi$, we will measure an angle $\theta$ around the smaller circle.

The position of a little piece of mass on the $r$-circle is therefore, in xy-coordinates, $\bar R [\cos\phi, \sin\phi] + r [\cos(\phi+\theta), \sin(\phi+\theta)]$ and its velocity is $$\vec v(\phi,\theta) = \bar R ~\Omega [-\sin\phi,\cos\phi] + r(\omega + \Omega) [-\sin(\phi+\theta), \cos(\phi+\theta)],$$ where I have defined $\Omega = d\phi/dt$ and $\omega = d\theta/dt.$

Its squared velocity is therefore:$$v^2 = (\bar R ~\Omega)^2 + [r(\omega + \Omega)]^2 + 2\bar R ~\Omega~r(\omega + \Omega)\cos(\theta).$$
Integrating with a linear mass density $dm = \lambda~r~d\theta,$ $m = 2 \pi r~\lambda,$ the big effect is that the cosine disappears and we're just left with:$$K = \int dK = \int \frac12 ~dm~ v^2 = \frac12 m \left[\bar R^2 \Omega^2 + r^2 (\omega+\Omega)^2\right]$$
Now for **rolling without slipping** on a stationary surface we need a velocity of zero at the angle $\theta = \pi,$ so $\bar R\Omega - r (\omega + \Omega) = 0,$ and $\omega = \frac{\bar R - r}{r} ~\Omega.$

So in terms of $\Omega$ (which for you is $v/(R + r)$) and $R = \bar R - r,$ and generalizing from our $mr^2$ to a moment of inertia $I$, we can see that the proper expression is $$K = \frac12 \left[m (R+r)^2 + I~\left(\frac Rr + 1\right)^2\right]~\Omega^2 = \frac12 m v^2 + \frac12 I \left(\frac vr\right)^2.$$So your **first method is correct** when we carefully analyze it from the second method's perspective.

## What went wrong?

Now that we know what's right, what went wrong in your second argument?

Your second method appears to suffer from an unnecessary duplication of $I$ and the assumption that $\omega = v/r$ rather than the correct $\omega = R v / [r (R + r)].$ This difference probably comes from you forgetting that your new coordinates are **rotating with respect to the old coordinates**, so some of the $v/r$ rotation is already incorporated in them. This presumably generates the discrepancy factor when fully taken into account.